# How do you list the table names of a Jet database in Perl with DBI?

Tags: perl, odbc, dbi, jet

Is there a portable way to list the table names in `*.mdb` files
(i.e. Microsoft Jet databases, also known as "Access databases") in Perl?

Usually I run my Perl scripts on Windows with Cygwin.

I can run SQL queries on `*.mdb` databases just fine with the `DBD::ODBC` module, but it doesn't implement DBI's `table_info` function, which would do exactly what I need.  The `DBD::ADO` and/or `Win32::OLE` modules can probably be used instead, but they refuse to install under Cygwin, and I'd prefer to have a portable solution - ideally one that even works on Linux.

The `DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader` module can be used to do this, and I understand it's being upgraded so it will actually work on `*.mdb` files, but it has an enormous list of dependencies that I don't really want to install wherever I run my script just to get this single function.

Have you ever written Perl code that lists the table names in an `*.mdb` file?
Which technique did you use and why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Where has this rumor come from that DBD::ODBC does not support table_info - this is the third time in a week I've seen it:

```
perl -le 'use DBI; my $h = DBI->connect("dbi:ODBC:access_sample"); my $t = $h->table_info(undef, undef, undef, "TABLE");print DBI::dump_results($t);'

'/home/martin/test.mdb', undef, 'A', 'TABLE', undef
'/home/martin/test.mdb', undef, 'MSysNavPaneGroupCategories', 'TABLE', undef
'/home/martin/test.mdb', undef, 'MSysNavPaneGroupToObjects', 'TABLE', undef
'/home/martin/test.mdb', undef, 'MSysNavPaneGroups', 'TABLE', undef
'/home/martin/test.mdb', undef, 'MSysNavPaneObjectIDs', 'TABLE', undef
'/home/martin/test.mdb', undef, 'PERL_DBD_TABLE1', 'TABLE', undef
'/home/martin/test.mdb', undef, 'PERL_DBD_TEST', 'TABLE', undef
'/home/martin/test.mdb', undef, 'TestTable', 'TABLE', undef
'/home/martin/test.mdb', undef, 'X', 'TABLE', undef
'/home/martin/test.mdb', undef, 'unicode', 'TABLE', undef
10 rows
```

Comment: Well, in my case, I was getting the error: `DBD::ODBC::db table_info failed: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver]Optional feature not implemented  (SQL-HYC00) at (...)` ... but I wasn't supplying undef as the first three parameters.    I misinterpreted the error message to mean that the whole `table_info` function is not supported.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the whole thing, then just grab the necessary parts from [DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader::DBI::ADO::MS_Jet](http://cpan.uwinnipeg.ca/htdocs/DBIx-Class-Schema-Loader/DBIx/Class/Schema/Loader/DBI/ADO/MS_Jet.pm.html).